# I don't get why this query doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I have a very classical many-to-many relationship. Like this: a table `groupe`:

```
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| val           | text                | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A table `groupe_valeur`:

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| groupe_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| valeur_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And a table `valeur`:

```
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| val           | text                | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have put in `groupe` 3 rows: one for `prenom` (= name in english), one for male `masculin` and one for female `feminin`.

```
SELECT g.id, g.val
FROM groupe g
WHERE g.val='prenom' OR g.val='masculin' OR val='feminin';
+---------+----------+
| id      | val      |
+---------+----------+
| 6041745 | feminin  |
| 6041744 | masculin |
| 6041746 | prenom   |
+---------+----------+
```

I've got all french names for male and female. For each name, I've made two "links" betwen `groupe` and `valeur`: one with the value `prenom` and one with either `masculin` or `feminin`.
Let's try with `Erika`:

```
SELECT g.val, gp.*, v.val
FROM groupe g 
JOIN groupe_valeur gp ON gp.groupe_id=g.id
JOIN valeur v ON v.id=gp.valeur_id
WHERE v.val like 'Erika';
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| val     | groupe_id | valeur_id | val   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| feminin |   6041745 |   6095430 | Erika |
| prenom  |   6041746 |   6095430 | Erika |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

This seems fine. Now I want to choose a random value.

```
SELECT val
FROM valeur v
JOIN groupe_valeur gv ON v.id=gv.valeur_id
WHERE gv.groupe_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val IN ('prenom', 'masculin')
)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;

+------------+
| val        |
+------------+
| Ziad       |
| Rosanna    |
| Vincent    |
| Soraya     |
| Gabriela   |
| Florent    |
+------------+
```

This doesn't work and gives me both male and female names! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to do two joins to get `prenom` and `masculin`.  The way your query is setup it gets `OR`.

Comment: what do you mean by random value! is it random values!? as I see you are doing limit 30 and your where in is for both groups, therefore, you will keep getting male and female groups!!

Comment: Just remove `prenom` from the `IN` list.

Comment: Your descriptions of the tables and their correlation to each other makes some sense, however, your data is lacking.  I would suggest editing your question and showing sample data from EACH table and how multiple values are established such as your "name" and "gender" and (whatever else) for a person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan's answer put me on the right track - even though his answer isn't working properly - see my comments. Here's the working solution that I can use in a `foreach()` loop in Php to add as many `group` values that act like filters as I want:

```
SELECT v.val
FROM valeur v
JOIN (
   SELECT gv.valeur_id
   FROM groupe_valeur gv
   JOIN groupe g ON g.id = gv.groupe_id  and g.val = 'feminin'
) as g0 ON g0.valeur_id = v.id
JOIN (
   SELECT gv.valeur_id
   FROM groupe_valeur gv
   JOIN groupe g ON g.id = gv.groupe_id  and g.val = 'prenom'
) as g1 ON g1.valeur_id = v.id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is your problem:

```
SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val IN ('prenom', 'masculin')
```

The `IN` operator will accept group values that are either "masculin" or "prenom" and all values are prénoms, ergo, this subquery will return all first names! I suggest you execute that query, all by itself, on your database and check the results.

```
 SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val = 'masculin'
```

should work or, even better, reqrite your query:

```
SELECT val
FROM valeur v
JOIN groupe_valeur gv ON v.id=gv.valeur_id
JOIN groupe g ON gv.groupe_id = g.id
WHERE g.val = 'masculin'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;
```

If you intend on adding new groups ("nom", for instance, for last names), you do it this way:

```
SELECT val
FROM valeur v
JOIN groupe_valeur gv ON v.id=gv.valeur_id
JOIN groupe g1 ON gv.groupe_id = g.id
JOIN groupe g2 ON gv.groupe_id = g.id
WHERE g1.val = 'masculin'
AND g2.val = 'prenom'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: Your (first) query will only return `masculin` over and over and over.

Comment: I've tried `SELECT v.val FROM valeur v JOIN groupe_valeur gv ON v.id=gv.valeur_id LEFT JOIN groupe g0 ON g0.id=gv.groupe_id AND g0.id=(SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val='feminin') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20;` and it takes ages to get a result (knowing that the table `valeur` has more than 8 000 000 rows and my query in my question takes 0.07s to execute)

Comment: Another try: `SELECT v.val FROM valeur v JOIN groupe_valeur gv ON v.id=gv.valeur_id LEFT JOIN groupe g0 ON g0.id=gv.groupe_id LEFT JOIN groupe g1 ON g1.id=gv.groupe_id WHERE g0.id=(SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val='feminin') AND g1.id=(SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val='prenom') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20;
Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: I've tried another way, which gives me empty set too: `SELECT v.val
FROM groupe_valeur gv
JOIN groupe g0 ON g0.id=gv.groupe_id
AND g0.id=(SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val='feminin')
JOIN groupe g1 ON g1.id=gv.groupe_id
AND g1.id=(SELECT id FROM groupe WHERE val='prenom')
JOIN valeur v ON v.id=gv.valeur_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:  First get 30 random males and then get the names of the males:

```
SELECT v.val 
FROM valeur v
JOIN (
   SELECT gv.valeur_id
   FROM groupe_valeur gv 
   JOIN groupe g ON g.id = gv.groupe_id  and g.val = 'masculin '
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30
) as der ON der.valeur_id = v.id
JOIN groupe_valeur gv2 ON gv2.valeur_id = v.id 
JOIN groupe g2 ON g2.id = gv2.groupe_id and g2.val='prenom'
```

Comment: I've tried your solution until it worked. It worked, but I'm trying to look for a solution which can add many `group` values (eg person, female, and classical (or old-fashionned or whatever))

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but here's my wild guess: you say "first get 30 random males". Suppose that some of the males are *not* `prenom`. Let's say 15. So you get 15 males that are, say animals, and 15 `prenom`. Your query *may* just return 15 `prenom`. Am I right?